# How to show in the browser the aggregated value of a relationship property as a single relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Below are my nodes and their properties:

```
| Node   | Property |
=====================
|Person  | id, name |
|Product | id, name |
|Buys    | amount   |
```

This query sums the amount paid by each person for a given product:

```
MATCH (t:Person)-[r:Buys]->(p:Product) 
return t,p, sum(r.amount) as Amount
```

Sadly, the browser continues to display multiple relationships between each `Person` and `Product` if there were multiple such purchases. I would only like to see *one* relationship between a given person and a given product, showing the sum --  rather than multiple relationships.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I just tested this query in a console and it works as expected, amount is aggregated by product. What you want is showing a virtual relationship (so this relationship doesn't exist) and it is currently not possible in the neo4j browser.

Comment: Thanks @ Christophe Willemsen. Hopefully future releases  will make it possible.